# Can you put fixed tabs inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-tabs

Right now I have a Navigation Drawer as the main activity, holding multiple fragments.

I was wondering if it is possible to have fixed tabs inside one of these fragments? I know nested activities is deprecated, so how would I go about this?

This tutorial shows me how to add fixed tabs on an activity only. 
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Update: I found the partial answer here ([How to open a new fragment from the navigation drawer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303314/how-to-open-a-new-fragment-from-the-navigation-drawer)).

Do I still need to create an adapter for the tab host?

Comment: Do you want have tabs inside fragment without using actionbar?

Comment: I can still use the action

Comment: You can create custom tab from RadioGroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using TabHost solves the problem.