# Navigation Drawer open a new Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I open a new Android Studio project with a Navigation Drawer Activity. So there are activty_main.xml, app_bar_main.xml, content_main.xml and a nav_header_main.xml in the layout-folder and a Java-Class MainActivity.

When an item in the Navigation Drawer is used, should open a new fragment. In the fragment have to be the Navigation Drawer too. How can I this avaible to API 8. How can I do this? How open a new Fragment?

**activity_main:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainAcitvity:**

```
package de.computerfreak.app.test;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment newFragment;
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
        // Handle the camera action
        newFragment = new f1();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Sorry for my english and thanks for your help!

Comment: Check this answer: [How to open a new fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303314/how-to-open-a-new-fragment-from-the-navigation-drawer)

Comment: Thanks, but which id i use in transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);

Comment: `R.id.content_frame` is a `<FrameLayout/>` that should be in the `activity_navigation_drawer ` layout. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I try a lot but it does not work. If I click a item nothing happens. I update the code above. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I implemented this in one of my own solutions, just switch values where appropriate:

```
 mNavigationView = (NavigationView) (findViewById(R.id.nav_menu));
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.menuEvents:
                {
                    mFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, new eventFragment());
                    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Upcoming Events");
                    //item.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                }

                case R.id.menuTechnique:
                {
                    mFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, new techniqueFragment());
                    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Useful Techniques");
                    //item.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                }

                case R.id.menuLink:
                {
                    mFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, new linkFragment());
                    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Helpful Links");
                    //item.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                }

                case R.id.menuSettings:
                {
                    mFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, new settingFragment());
                    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Settings");
                    //item.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```